# Adding set column values as min/max error bars on R

Tags: r, sorting, ggplot2, dataset

Apologies if this has been asked before, but it is difficult to articulate in order to find an answer.

I have the following set of data below. In R, I would like to construct a bar plot for `PV1` and `PV2` for `AvgRead` and `AvgUniq`. For the error bars, I would like to set `MinRead` and `MinUniq` as the minima, and `MaxRead` and `MaxUniq` as the maxima.

If you could help that would be greatly appreciated. Again my apologies if this has been asked before.

```
         AvgRead  MinRead  MaxRead AvgUniq MinUniq MaxUniq
PV1          20     10        40     40       20     80
PV2          40     20        80     80       40     160
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reshape your data a little bit using the `melt()` and `dcast()` functions from `reshape2`:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
  row.names = c("PV1", "PV2"),
  AvgRead = c(20, 40),
  MinRead = c(10, 20),
  MaxRead = c(40, 80),
  AvgUniq = c(40, 80),
  MinUniq = c(20, 40),
  MaxUniq = c(70, 160)
)

df$name <- row.names(df)

df_molten <- melt(df)
df_molten$var1 <- substr(df_molten$variable, 1, 3)
df_molten$var2 <- substr(df_molten$variable, 4, 10000)

df_cast <- dcast(df_molten, name + var2 ~ var1, value.var = "value")

ggplot(data = df_cast, aes(x = name, y = Avg, fill = var2)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  geom_errorbar(
    aes(ymin = Min, ymax = Max),
    width = 0.5,
    size = 1.3,
    position = position_dodge(0.9)
  )
```

[image]

**EDIT:** to change the order of the bars you need to change var2 to factors and sort the levels accordingly:

```
df_cast <- dcast(df_molten, name + var2 ~ var1, value.var = "value")
df_cast$var2 <- factor(df_cast$var2, levels = c("Uniq", "Read"))

ggplot(data = df_cast, aes(x = name, y = Avg, fill = var2)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  geom_errorbar(
    aes(ymin = Min, ymax = Max),
    width = 0.5,
    size = 1.3,
    position = position_dodge(0.9)
  )
```

Comment: Thank you very much Brett, that is most helpful! One more thing, though I am trying to sort it out myself as well, is what if I want to plot the Uniq data before the Read data?

Comment: you need to make var2 into factors, see my edited answer

Comment: That makes sense. Many thanks for your help, it's greatly appreciated

Comment: No problem! please consider accepting my answer if you find it sufficient :)

Comment: Oops, my apologies! I'm quite new to this! All done, thanks again!